# Implement div group hide / show

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to implement a mechanism to hide / show div within a group meaning that I want to only have one div displayed for the group. Of course, I can implement this using the ng-show directive but I would like to have something more generic.

For example:

```
<div div-group="mygroup">
  <div id="div1"> ... </div>
  <div id="div2"> ... </div>
  <div id="div3"> ... </div>
</div>
```

If I call a function like showDiv("div1"), other div would be hidden (div2 and div3). I thought about adding an object on the root scope containing all inner div status (displayed or hidden).

Thanks very much for your help!
Thierry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be using ng-class

```
.show{
display:block
}

.hide{
display:none;
}

<div div-group="mygroup">
  <div id="div1" ng-class={true:'show',false:'hide'}[selecteddiv='div1']> ... </div>
  <div id="div2" ng-class={true:'show',false:'hide'}[selecteddiv='div2']> ... </div>
  <div id="div3" ng-class={true:'show',false:'hide'}[selecteddiv='div3']> ... </div>
</div>

$scope.choose=function(id){
$scope.selecteddiv=id;
}
```

> So you could pass proper id as string in function

Comment: `ng-class` accepts a map, as you have demonstrated, but the names of the properties of the map should be the class while the property value should result in true or false. In your example, it is the other way around...

Comment: this is one more syntax of declaring the ng-class i have used it many times before

Answer (score -2):

If you want to do this in vanilla js, you just can write your `showDiv` function like this

```
function showDiv(id) {
  //hide all divs
  document.findElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
  document.findElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';
  document.findElementById('div3').style.display = 'none';
  //show just the div you want
  document.findElementById(id).style.display = 'block'; //or whatever it was before
}
```

Comment: you should mention angular way of doing it